# Unable to print vector object data member values in C++

Tags: c++, oop, vector, logic

I am creating a snakes and ladders game. For now, I have created two classes `board` and `ladders`. The board is responsible for printing the board and the ladder is responsible for all ladder functionality. 
Here is my `ladder.h` class:

```
#ifndef LADDER_H
#define LADDER_H

#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

class Ladder
{
private:
    unsigned int m_Ladder_bottom, m_Ladder_top, m_Ladder_number;
    static int m_Ladder_counter;
    const static int m_Ladder_ladderBottom[6];
    const static int m_Ladder_ladderTop[6];
public:
    // Constructor
    Ladder() {
            m_Ladder_bottom = m_Ladder_ladderBottom[m_Ladder_counter - 1];
            m_Ladder_top = m_Ladder_ladderTop[m_Ladder_counter - 1];
            m_Ladder_number = m_Ladder_counter;
            ++m_Ladder_counter;
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const Ladder &ladder) {
            os << "Ladder Number: " << ladder.m_Ladder_number << "\nLadder Top Position: " << 
            ladder.m_Ladder_top << "\nLadder Bottom Position: " << ladder.m_Ladder_bottom;
            os << "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            ------------------\n";
            return os;
    }
};

int Ladder::m_Ladder_counter = 1;
const int Ladder::m_Ladder_ladderBottom[6] = { 4, 12, 14, 22, 41, 54 };
const int Ladder::m_Ladder_ladderTop[6] = { 56, 50, 55, 58, 79, 88 };

#endif // !LADDER_H
```

Here is my `board.h` class:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <vector>
#include "Ladder.h"

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

class Board
{
private:
    vector<Ladder> m_Board_ladders;
public:
    Board() {
        m_Board_ladders.reserve(6);
    }

    void m_Board_PrintLadders() {
        vector<Ladder>::const_iterator iter;
        for (iter = m_Board_ladders.begin(); iter != m_Board_ladders.end(); ++iter) {
            cout << *iter << '\n';
        }
    }
};


#endif // !BOARD_H
```

In my `main` class when I create an object of type `ladder`, I am printing all the ladder locations successfully:

```
#include "Ladder.h"
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<Ladder> ladders(6);
    vector<Ladder>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter = ladders.begin(); iter != ladders.end(); ++iter) {
        cout  << *iter;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Here is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtZZr.png 
Although, when I create an object of type `board` and then try to print all the ladders (even tho I have the same exact code copy-pasted), it does not work? Here is my main class with `board` object:

```
#include "Board.h"

using std::cout;

int main() {
    Board board;
    board.m_Board_PrintLadders();

    system("pause");
}
```

Here is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2YXt.png

**Why is it not printing anything?** 
 **Thank You!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Ladders` version you are creating a `vector` of 6 elements.

For the `Boards` version, you don't get any output because `m_Board_ladders` is empty when you construct the `Board`. Note that calling `reserve` doesn't actually change the size of a `vector`:

```
Board() {
    m_Board_ladders.reserve(6);  // still empty
}
```

If you want the `vector` to have 6 elements, you can do:

```
Board() : m_Board_ladders(6) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e9zTn8).

Comment: Ok but I atleast have one instance of that object created right? Since I create an instance of ```ladder``` should it not atleast print out 1 value? I have a ladder constructor that initializes all the values! By the way your solution totally worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As far as `Board` is concerned, there are no objects in the `vector` `m_Board_ladders`. The `Ladder` object you create is completely independent of any `Ladder`s in a `Board` object.

Comment: Doesn't this line create 1 object? ```vector<Ladder> m_Board_ladders;```
If it does, should it not atleast initialize 1 value to it using the ```ladder``` constructor?

Comment: No, that line creates a vector with 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

@ProgrammingRage : you have not initialised your `Board.m_Board_ladders`, you have just called the allocator with the `reserve()` command to book it some space.

You have to initialise `m_Board_ladders = Ladder()` once you reserve the space, so that the constructor for `Ladder` gets actually called.

Better still, do not declare the `Board()` constructor in your class at all, leave it to the compiler to synthesize it, and it will create it correctly.

Comment: How will the board constructor know the amount of ladder objects to create?

Comment: `Ladder()` will always create a Ladder 6 elements long, which will be a `vector` so its length will expanded dynamically (to 6 here) according to necessity. Hence the other member routine in `Board` will know where `m_Board_ladders.end()` is, it doesn't really need to know its size in advance for constructing it, if it is a `vector<Ladder>`.